# ボタンを押しているときにimage viewをちょっとずつ動かすアニメーションについて

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode6, storyboard, uikit

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
  　      self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);}
completion:^ 
{
}];
```

上記のアニメーションの書き方は途中で止めるのに向いていないことは分かりました。

ストーリーボードを使っていて `UIControlEventTouchDown` の `sender` です

```
- (IBAction)botan:(UIButton *)sender {
    CGRect frame = self.viewname.frame;
    frame.origin.x += 5;
    [self.viewname setFrame:frame];
}
```

これを、ボタンが押されている限り繰り返させるのはどうしたらいいんでしょうか
繰り返せたとして滑らかではないと思うのですがどうしたら滑らかに動かせるんでしょうか

ド初心者なので触って覚えていこうと思っています
宜しくお願いします

Answer (score 3):

アニメーションといわれて、まず思い浮かぶのが、UIViewの「animation〜」で始まるメソッド群と、CAAnimationフレームワークですが、これらは、画面遷移のときに、ビューを左右上下にスライドさせるとか、オブジェクトをタップしたら、すこし震えてみせるとか、ユーザ操作に反応していることを示す、視覚効果で使うことを意図したもので、せいぜい1秒以下のアニメーションが、前提になっています。
iOS 7より、UIDynamicsという、よりおおがかりなアニメーションを、UIViewサブクラスに与えるフレームワークが追加されました。これはCPUでなくGPU（Graphic Proccessing Unit）を使うので、マシンの負担が小さいわりに、スムーズなアニメーションを実現できます。

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

// アニメーションの対象のイメージビュー、imageView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
// UIViewにアニメーション機能を追加するクラス、UIDynamicAnimator
@property (nonatomic) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // ViewControllerのベースビューに、アニメーションを組みこむ。
    self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView: self.view];
}

// 画面上の任意の場所をタップ。
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // 「ふるまい」を定義するクラスを生成。このふるまいに従うアイテム（UIViewサブクラス）を配列（NSArray）で登録。
    UIDynamicItemBehavior *moveBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems: @[self.imageView]];
    // 直線運動という「ふるまい」を定義。方向とスピード、動かすアイテムを指定。
    [moveBehavior addLinearVelocity: CGPointMake(0.0, 50.0) forItem: self.imageView];
    // アニメーション開始。
    [self.animator addBehavior: moveBehavior];
}

// タップした指を、画面から離す。
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // アニメーションの終了。
    [self.animator removeAllBehaviors];
}

@end
```

タップにより、断続的にimageViewが移動することを、確認してください。
UIDynamicsは、ほかに円運動もできますし、重力によってビューが落下することも実現できます。すこし勉強をする必要がありますが、それに振り向けた労力以上の効果を得ることができるはずです。

Comment: pt/秒の移動の場合、タッチを離して停止するタイミングによって、座標の値が半端になってビューがボヤけることがありませんか？　そのあたりのアドバイスもあると、この方法を採るときに助かると思います。

Comment: @dokubeko そういう現象が起きた経験はありません。それを再現する条件を教えていただければ、検証してみます。

Comment: だったら問題ないのかなと思います。こういう移動時ではないのですが、描画時に半端な値でボヤけた経験があったものですから。

Comment: @dokubeko NSLog()で、アニメーション停止時のimageViewの座標を調べましたが、小数点以下は、.0か.5となっていました。そこらへんはiOSのほうで対処しているということではないでしょうか？

Comment: かつて[小数点の座標を指定すると描画がぼやける仕様](http://kishikawakatsumi.hatenablog.com/entry/20100527/1274910461)がありましたが、すでに修正されています。iOS5くらいの話じゃないですかこれ。

Comment: 確認できました。させたかった動きをしました。
アニメーションといっても、色々な種類があり、用途によって使い分けるのとその種類の知識を増やしていかなければいけないことがわかりました。

Answer (score 1):

例えば、タイマーで繰り返し処理するならこんな感じじゃないでしょうか。

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)didTouchDownButton:(id)sender { // Touch Down に結びつけ

  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.01f // スピードは繰り返し間隔であるこの値で調節
                 target: self
                 selector: @selector(translateViewName:)
                 userInfo: nil
                 repeats: YES];
}

- (IBAction)didTouchUpOrCancel:(id)sender { // Touch Cancel, Touch Up Inside, Touch Up Outside に結びつけ

  [self.timer invalidate]; // タイマーを止める
  self.timer = nil;
}

- (void)translateViewName:(NSTimer *)timer {

  CGRect frame = self.viewname.frame;
  frame.origin.x += 1.0f; // 視認上、最小単位である1ポイント以下の移動なら滑らかに見えるはず
  [self.viewname setFrame: frame];
}

@end
```

ほか、例えば長押しの検出などは UILongPressGesuture を使う、繰り返し実行には UIScreen の - displayLinkWithTarget:selector: を使う、などが考えられると思います。また、CALayer の暗黙的/明示的なアニメーションとモデル層/プレゼンテーション層の違いなども学習すると、また異なった方法を利用できるかもしれません。

Comment: NSTimerを使った繰り返しの方法がよくわかって非常に助かりました。　　
     CGRect frame = self.viewname.frame;　　
  frame.origin.x += 1.0f;　　
     [self.viewname setFrame: frame];　　

このやり方で非常に綺麗に動くことが確認できました。
しかし、別のメソッドにも同じように書くとframe.origin.xでは値が最初の位置になってしまいます。
何が悪いのかはよくわかるのですが、移動後の座標の取得をどう行えばいいのかがわかりませんでした。
それができれば４方向に自由に移動させることができると思います。
UIScreenも調べて考えてみようと思います。

Comment: ゲームか何かの方向キーをスクリーン上に再現しようとしているように見えますが、そうであればまた別の質問でそのようにアドバイスを求めたほうがよいと思います。要件と制約によって、手法の選択肢が変わります。